# Checking the capacity of a trip at register

Tags: mysql, sql

These are the database table i have:

## trip

- id
- capacity
- ...

## tripRegisteration

- id
- tripId
- firstname
- lastname
- phone
- ...
- registerationState

## what i can do

I want a sql query which will give me the trips which has enough free capacity. The `tripRegisteration.registerationState` for valid registeration is `approved`.

Of course i can first do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM tripRegisteration 
WHERE registerationState = "approved"
GROUP BY tripId
```

Then i have a table which would tell me each trip registered and then i can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM trip
WHERE capacity < PhpReplacesThis AND id=PhpReplacesThisToo
```

But for each trip i have to execute the above code, it consumes so much time and the resources start to run out, and because there are a lot of trips (and a lot of sql queries) it wouldn't be efficient.

## What i can't do but it's nice

It would be much more efficient if i could do that in just one sql query, which would give me a table which contains the trips which has enough capacity.

Is it really nice? Well my measurement shows that when the number of sql queries i run with `php` is so much the application would start crawling and consume a lot of time. I remember if i make sql queries compact (one bigger query instead of a million small query) it would make the whole application much faster. I just have experienced it and measured the time in another project if i am wrong correct me. Of course that's another question and this explanation is written for making the situation clear. My main question is how i can get the result in one sql query?

Comment: You need to use a `JOIN`

Comment: i know `JOIN` but how i can use `COUNT` and check the capacity?

Comment: Should be able to use a sub-select to get count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query uses just a JOIN and no nested-queries

```
SELECT trip.id,trip.capacity,trip.moreColumns,count(*) as number_of_registrations
FROM trip 
JOIN tripRegisteration
ON trip.id=tripRegisteration.tripId
WHERE registerationState = "approved"
GROUP BY trip.id,trip.capacity,trip.moreColumns
HAVING trip.capacity< number_of_registrations
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use a join and subselect, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM trip LEFT JOIN (select count(1) as regCount, 
tripId from tripRegisteration where tripId = trip.id and 
registerationState="approved") as registrations 
ON registrations.tripId = trip.id 
WHERE trip.capacity < registrations.regCount
```

Comment: Yep its called a subselect or subquery. Better start doing some more reading :)

Comment: sql says unknown column trip.id

Comment: there is no need for `WHERE tripId = trip.id` it can simply be replaced with `GROUP BY tripId`. :)